# how to change chrome extension owner email

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I created a google chrome extension, and I wanna move the ownership to different user by changing email I use to upload the extension.
is that possible? if yes, How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just fill up [this form](http://support.google.com/chrome_webstore/bin/request.py?contact_type=dev_account_transfer) to transfer ownership.